# SQL IF ELSE Statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, authentication, oracle-apex

In Oracle apex I am using a custom authentication system. Whereby it gets the username and passwords from a users table, Currently when logged in as a normal user you can only view your own records and edit them for security reasons. 
with this as example of the SQL,

```
select 
"RECORD_NUMBER",
"STUDENT_FIRST_NAME",
"STUDENT_SURNAME",
"USERNAME"
"PASSWORD"
from   "USERS"
where upper(USERNAME) = upper(v('APP_USER'))
```

However one of the Users is called admin in the table, how can I make it if I'm logged in with the user admin I can view everyone's records in the table, never really delved this deep before so could do with some help.

Comment: For performance reasons I recommend calling v() to get the app user and put it in a local variable, then refer to the variable in the query. Especially if (as in the suggested answer below) you are going to refer to it more than once in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used apex, so I hope your sql is somehow using bind variables, but here is the general idea:

```
select 
"RECORD_NUMBER",
"STUDENT_FIRST_NAME",
"STUDENT_SURNAME",
"USERNAME"
"PASSWORD"
from   "USERS"
where upper(USERNAME) = upper(v('APP_USER'))
or upper(v('APP_USER')) = 'ADMIN'
```

Comment: thought about this but did not think it would be that simple, thank you.